# SQL JOIN query comparison

Tags: sql, join

The following explanation is from the book: Graph databases. by Robinson, Ian, Jim Webber, and Emil Eifrem. at " O'Reilly Media, Inc.", 2013.

---

Say there are 2 tables:

**Person**

```
ID, Person
1, Alice  
2, Bob  
..,..  
99, Zach
```

**PersonFriend**

```
ID, Person 
1, 2   
2, 1  
2, 99  
..,..  
99,1
```

Example 2-1. Bob’s friends

```
SELECT p1.Person 
FROM Person p1 
    JOIN PersonFriend   
        ON PersonFriend.FriendID = p1.ID  
    JOIN Person p2  
        ON PersonFriend.PersonID = p2.ID  
WHERE p2.Person = 'Bob'
```

Based on our sample data, the answer is Alice and Zach. This isn’t a particularly expensive or difficult query, because it constrains the number of rows under consideration using the filter WHERE Person.person='Bob'.

Friendship isn’t always a reflexive relationship, so in Example 2-2, we ask the reciprocal query, which is, “who is friends with Bob

Example 2-2. Who is friends with Bob?

```
SELECT p1.Person 
FROM Person p1 
     JOIN PersonFriend  
        ON PersonFriend.PersonID = p1.ID 
     JOIN Person p2
        ON PersonFriend.FriendID = p2.ID 
WHERE p2.Person = 'Bob'
```

The answer to this query is Alice; sadly, Zach doesn’t consider Bob to be a friend. This reciprocal query is still easy to implement, but on the database side it’s more expensive, because the database now has to consider all the rows in the PersonFriend table. We can add an index, but this still involves an expensive layer of indirection.

---

Everything above comes from the book and is not my opinion. What I dont understand
1) why query in example 2-2 is more expensive than one in example 2-1?
2) why is it called a reciprocal query?

Comment: What makes you think one query would perform worse than the other?  Have you checked the execution plans of both?  Specifically, if you have the appropriate indices setup on the two tables, either query could probably be made to run fast.

Answer (score 0):

1. The only thing I see that would affect the performance would be how indexes are defined.
   **Case 1:** your only index is on `(PersonID, FriendID)`. All the DBs I know will create B-tree index as the default and will be able to use it for search on `PersonID` alone. Consequence: the part `ON PersonFriend.PersonID = p2.ID WHERE p2.Person = 'Bob'` will probably use it and be fast. For the second query, this will not be the case.
   **Case 2:** You have 2 separate indexes, one on each column `(PersonID)` and `(FriendID)`. In that situation, the 2 queries will be equivalent in terms of performance (they will just use each of the indexes).
2. Do not take **reciprocal query** as a technical term because that is not what it is.
   The author simply inverted the `JOIN`. In the first query, `FriendID` appears first and `PersonID` second. This gives the answer to : Whom does Bob like?
   In opposite, the second query makes the joins against `PersonID` first and `FriendID` second. This gives the answer to: Who likes Bob? (that is: was friendship **reciprocal**)